# Is the rank of a matrix unaffected by congruence transformations?

Tags: linear-algebra

Sorry for the easy question but if I have a square matrix $A$ over $\mathbb C$ then is its rank invariant under a congruence transformation $A \mapsto P^t AP$ ? What's the easiest way to see this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $M$ is invertible, then the vectors $v_1,...,v_k$ are linearly independent **iff** the vectors $M v_1,...,M v_k$ are. The same applies to $M^{-1}$, of course.

It is easy to see that ${\cal R}C = {\cal R}(CM)$ for any matrix $C$.

It is also easy to see that ${\cal R}(MC) = M ({\cal R}C)$. In particular, the above shows that $\dim {\cal R}(MC) = \dim {\cal R}C$.

In the above case this gives ${\cal R}(P^TAP) = P^T {\cal R} (A P) = P^T {\cal R} A$, hence $\dim {\cal R}(P^TAP) = \dim {\cal R} A$.

Answer (score 1):

This is true if $P$ is invertible.  Noting that $\operatorname{rank}(AB) \leq \min\{\operatorname{rank}(A),\operatorname{rank}(B)\}$, we have $\operatorname{rank}(AB) = \operatorname{rank}(BA) = \operatorname{rank}(A)$ whenever $B$ is invertible.  Thus, 
$$
\operatorname{rank}(P^TAP) = \operatorname{rank}(P^TA) =
\operatorname{rank}(A)
$$